# why can't I assign collections to each other?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have inheritance hierarchy Shape->Rectangle->Square

And I have ShapeCollection class with parameter T to put there any of shape class type: Shape, Rectangle, Square.
But I don't understand, why this is work:

```
List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Shape> shapeList = rectangleList;
```

But this is doesn't work

```
List<ShapeCollection<Rectangle>> recCallList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>> shapeCallList = recCallList;
```

Comment: How is the `ShapeCollection` defined? Could you show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java Generics are invariant, meaning that `List<S>` and `List<T>` are unrelated types even if `S` is a subtype of `T`.

In your case, this means that `List<ShapeCollection<Rectangle>>` is unrelated to `List<ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>>` even though `ShapeCollection<Rectangle>` is a subtype of `ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>>`.

If you want variance, you must declare that by using a bounded wildcard. That is, the common supertype of `List<Rectangle>` and `List<Circle>` is `List<? extends Shape>`. Likewise, the common supertype of `List<ShapeCollection<Rectangle>>` and `List<ShapeCollection<Circle>>` is `List<? extends ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>>`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `ShapeCollection` is declared with something like `class ShapeCollection<T extends Shape> {}`.

This is has to do with how [subtyping and wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) works in Java. Imagine that Java allowed you to do what you want:

```
List<ShapeCollection<Rectangle>> recCallList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>> shapeCallList = recCallList;  // imagine it's ok

ShapeCollection<Square> squareCollection = ...;
shapeCallList.add(squareCollection); // uh-oh, mix of Square and Rectangle
```

Now you can add a `ShapeCollection<Square>` to `recCallList`, which is bad. The reason you can do a `ShapeCollection<Square>` to a `List<ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>>` is that `ShapeCollection<Square>` is a subclass of `ShapeCollection<? extends Shape>`, as illustrated in this picture taken from Oracle docs:

[image]